# Вложенный файл приходит с расширением .dat и непонятным именем

Tags: email, php

Есть скрипт отправки письма с вложением. Проблема заключается в том, что файл приходит всегда с расширением .dat независимо от того, какое оно на самом деле и с каким-то произвольным именем. Вот сам скрипт, где может быть ошибка?

```
    $email = "text-mail@mail.ru";
    $subject = "Заголовок";
    $msg = "Текст письма";
    $headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";

    if (!empty($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
        $path = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
            $file = $path;
        }
    }

    if (empty($file)) {
        mail($email, $subject, $msg, $headers);
    } else {
        send_mail($email, $subject, $msg, $file);
    }

    header("Location: $_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]");
    exit();

function send_mail($email, $subject, $msg, $file)
{
    $fp = fopen($file, "r");
    $file = fread($fp, filesize($file));
    $boundary = "--" . md5(uniqid(time()));
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\n";
    $multipart .= "--$boundary\n";
    $multipart .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
    $multipart .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: Quot-Printed\n\n";
    $multipart .= "$msg\n\n";
    $message_part = "--$boundary\n";
    $message_part .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\n";
    $message_part .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
    $message_part .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"\n\n";
    $message_part .= chunk_split(base64_encode($file)) . "\n";
    $multipart .= $message_part . "--$boundary--\n";

    mail($email, $subject, $multipart, $headers);
}
```

И еще, как дополнительный вопрос: письмо отлично приходят на локальный сервер (денвер), но при проверке на реальном хостинге не доходят до mail.ru, в какую сторону копать?

Comment: Последняя проблема с mail.ru решилась, но главная осталась - вложения приходят с расширением .dat. Кто-нибудь знает в чем проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу предположить, что проблема вот в этом:

```
$message_part .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"\n\n";
```

У вас в переменной `$file` - содержимое файла. В данном контексте тут необходимо его название.

Comment: Действительно. Огромное спасибо! Исправил так: в функцию send_mail добавил строку $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name']; , а в ошибочной строке подставил это значение $message_part .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"\n\n";